# IF statements based on array item inside a foreach loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, file-get-contents

I have three variables, each one getting content from their respective files.  These three variables are in an array (called $array).  I'm running a foreach loop to look at the array, and another one to print a string of commands based on each line coming for each text file.

All works well, except, now I have to add an if statement to write-host a line based on where the address file it came from (my attempt with the `if ($_ -like '*beta3*') {write-Host "True"}` line didn't pan out.  The main idea is to add a comment string based on the data type--Each file is a 'data type'.

```
$beta1addresses = Get-Content betarun1.txt
$beta2addresses = Get-Content betarun2.txt
$beta3addresses = Get-Content betarun3.txt

$array = ($beta1addresses,$beta2addresses,$beta3addresses)

Write-Host "config this address"
foreach ($_ in $array){
foreach ($address in $_){
    Write-Host "edit ""$address"""
    Write-Host "set type fqdn"
if ($_ -like '*beta3*') {write-Host "set comment from_beta3_file"}
    Write-Host "set fqdn ""$address"""
    Write-Host "set visibility disable"
    Write-Host "next"
}}
```

Here's a demo of the current output (might give a better idea of what I'm trying to do)... only missing `set comment from_beta3_file` line since these came from that file:

```
edit "www.betaXyahoo.com"
set type fqdn
set fqdn "www.betaXyahoo.com"
set visibility disable
next
edit "www.betaXsimbrano.com"
set type fqdn
set fqdn "www.betaXsimbrano.com"
set visibility disable
next
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the bug, the code prints readily the `set comment from_beta3_file` on my test setup. As you don't have ` {write-Host "True"}` in the sample code but `write-Host "set comment from_beta3_file"`, please double-check that the pasted code is right. Maybe you have a typo in a variable name and that wrecks havoc?

Comment: Gah.. Sorry, messed up by providing an old demo output  (which as above currently reads www.beta3yahoo.com, etc...).   In reality the betarun3.txt file has  www.betaXyahoo.com--I named the domains in that file as betaX, so I would know that "True" will only show up IF it could recognize that the variable is coming from that file.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  I'm also trying a different way of accomplishing this.  Basically, for each item I'm looking to write "set comment filename_or_category" based on the content (which I was basing my files on: Service/Category).  The other way of doing this, looks like would be by combining all the data from my various files into a CSV, with two colums: Domains and Service/Category.  Then using the import-csv to bring it in and parse--wouldn't have to read filename in order to write where it came from or what it's purpose/service is.   Would def like answer for the above though.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the relevant data items. That is, sample file contents, desired output and actual output. Don't add those as comments, as those are hard to read.

Comment: Ok, updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$array` doesn't really care about the name of the variable (`$beta3addresses`) that used to refer to the data it now holds, so unless the `betarun3.txt` file actually contains a line with the string "beta3" in it, your `if()` statement will always return false.

There are several ways to get around this, I would probably go with a hashtable (if the files are always unchanged):

```
$Addresses = @{
    'beta1' = Get-Content '.\betarun1.txt'
    'beta2' = Get-Content '.\betarun2.txt'
    'beta3' = Get-Content '.\betarun3.txt'
}

Write-Host "config this address"
foreach ($Key in $Addresses.Keys){
    foreach ($address in $Addresses[$Key]){
        Write-Host "edit ""$address"""
        Write-Host "set type fqdn"
        if ($Key -eq 'beta3') {
            Write-Host "set comment from_beta3_file"
        }
        Write-Host "set fqdn ""$address"""
        Write-Host "set visibility disable"
        Write-Host "next"
    }
}
```

If the number of files vary, you could retrieve information about the file and use that instead:

```
foreach($File in Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD -Filter beta*.txt){
    foreach($address in Get-Content $File.FullName){
        if($File.Name -like '*beta3*'){ # do your thing }
    }
}
```